# Create a form and save data in a external DB with Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to create a form, not contact form, with some fields and then save this data to a external database trough Wordpress. Is that possible? How? I'm newbie with WP

Answer (score 1):

Use the exec-php plugin for WP to write some php code in your page/form and make it save data to an external DB ...

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exec-php/

Comment: can you give me a example of how to do this? I check the docs but really haven't idea in how to build the form because I'm not a WP expert just this is my first work with it. Thanks in advance

Comment: @ReynierPM You're really asking for a code solution without actually trying anything for yourself? Hamza gave you what you needed to get you started. Maybe you should TRY some things, and if you have trouble with YOUR code, you can open up a new question.

Comment: @maiorano84 you're right my bad. I leave the question open until I finish build this for not to open once new if I have some problems :)

Comment: would you please take a look and update the answer? this plugin doesnt work anymore